# How to create tables for eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I'm trying to implement eloquent ORM inside my Slim project. This is, for exemple my `Post` model.

```
class Post extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
  }

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
  }

  public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');
  }
}
```

After many research, I still don't have any ideas of how do I create my table in PhpMyAdmin. Which name for each column should I use ? How to make the many to many or one to many relations ?

Comment: Database design should come before the models. Sit down and figure what you want to capture, what each table should hold, and the names for each. Then create the table for each (migrations would be better than creating it directly, for ease of development->production). Then you can worry about your models.

Comment: I know exactly what each table should hold, but I don't know how to name my colmuns. For exemple for the many to many relation for the tag, in the user table how should I name the column ?

Comment: For one-to-one or one-to-many, "table_id" is the general convention. For many-to-many, read up on pivot tables.

Comment: If it's a convention, how do I say to eloquent that it'll find the one-to-many id in this specific column ? I didn't read anything about that..

Comment: Here's some [useful information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thank's I didn't see this page!